# integrate spring security and spring MVC and and spring integration with each other

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

I am currently developing a web site for having control over IOT devices by spring.
The application is based on spring boot.
I have developed most of rest API s by extending from **DataJpa**.
Next step I had to implement TCP connection in my application and after doing some
research I adopt **spring integration** for doing that and simple application worked well.
Next, I decided to add spring Integration to my application for only user authentication after that I configured that I realized that there are some conflicts
in my application and I received **java: cannot access javax.servlet.Filter class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found**.
I did some research in I found a related topic for spring webflux and it was said that I should implement spring security for webflux (integration in this case) not  for spring web.
Now about the main problem: as I said earlier the structure of application should be like this:
1- first part which is MVC based and there are some webpages and data should be stored in mySql or mariaDB, also i want to authenticate and authorize users by spring security.
2-Second part of application is implementation Tcp socket via Netty or spring integration for having an an alive connection between IOT devices and Server.

Now I am looking for a way to be able to say to spring that it should distinguish
these two different contexts from each other and not combine configurations with the other one while they must work with each other.

Is there any way for this separation and tell spring combine them with special responsible for each?

note that adding following dependency did not change anyThing

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>`
```

other dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

security Config :

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class securityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
appUserDetailService appUserDetailService;
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/","/home").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

error which occurs :

> java: cannot access javax.servlet.Filterclass file for javax.servlet.Filter not found

and points to first line of spring security configuration.
my application properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/testapp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.port=8081
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
```

Comment: You should be sure that you use Spring Boot `3.0.1` for Jakarta EE.

Comment: 3.0.2 is the latest.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I added the newest version all   dependencies but nothing changed. I have heard about both of   you a lot and happy to have a way for talking to you.  Are there any ways for config spring web Security and integration with each other?

Comment: You are probably using some other dependency that is not compatible with JEE 9/10 (classes are now in the `jakarta` namespace instead of `javax`). Look at the full stack trace to figure out which component is trying to use the old class.

Comment: the error is coming from:   /C:/Users/s.movahedi/Downloads/t1/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/security/securityConfig.java:[17,8]                                    cannot access javax.servlet.Filter                                                          
[ERROR]   class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found

Comment: So it's your demo app that needs to be changed to use `jakarta` instead of `javax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /C:/Users/s.movahedi/Downloads/t1/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/security/securityConfig.java:[17,8] cannot access javax.servlet.Filter [ERROR] class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found

So it's your demo app that needs to be changed to use `jakarta` instead of `javax` if you want to use Boot 3, Spring 6.

Comment: finally it started working. you were right. The problem was related to conflicts between Spring security and Javax.